# Issue with line width prittier/eslint airbnb styleguide

Tags: node.js, eslint, prettier

I am running into an issue where I can not get my `printWidth` settings to change. Regardless, of what value I put I can not get the `printWidth` settings to reflect.

Has anyone run into this before or see any glaring errors in my config files:

prittierrc.js

```
module.exports = {
  printWidth: 500,
  singleQuote: true,
  trailingComma: 'all',
};
```

eslintrc.js

```
const { off } = require('process');

module.exports = {
  extends: ['airbnb', 'plugin:prettier/recommended', 'prettier/react'],
  env: {
    browser: true,
    commonjs: true,
    es6: true,
    jest: true,
    node: true,
  },
  rules: {
    'jsx-a11y/href-no-hash': ['off'],
    'react/jsx-filename-extension': ['warn', { extensions: ['.js', '.jsx'] }],
    'max-len': [
      'warn',
      {
        code: 500,
        tabWidth: 2,
        comments: 250,
        ignoreComments: false,
        ignoreTrailingComments: true,
        ignoreUrls: true,
        ignoreStrings: true,
        ignoreTemplateLiterals: true,
        ignoreRegExpLiterals: true,
      },
    ],
    'no-unused-vars': 'warn',
    'no-console': 'off',
  },
};
```

how my editor looks:
[click here for imgur url](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R1Yor.png)

Its clearly not reflecting the `printWidth: 500` setting

Answer (score 1):

Check the spelling on you config file name.